# How to make 3 screens w/ 2 GPUs work on ubu18?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, amdgpu

My PC has an AMD+APU and an Nvidia 680TI.
I am booting a fresh install of Ubu18Desktop and when I have 3 monitors plugged in (HDMI, HDMI/DPort) I can only get as far as the login screen. After logging in the default window manager (for Ubu and tried with Kubu) just displays 3 black screens with a cursor that can scroll across all 3. **When I login with only the 2 NVIDIA screens plugged in, the desktop loads just fine.**
**How do I get the 3rd monitor plugged into the APU displaying?**

I haven't used linux for desktop since 2005, back then to do multiple monitors with multiple graphics cards I would edit the x11.conf file until it worked.

In this thread ([3+ monitors, nvidia + intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171222/3-monitors-nvidia-intel-graphics)) two points are made:

- don't edit the x11.conf
- ubuntu doesn't support driving multiple monitors from multiple drivers

...
thats pretty hard for me to believe. 
Another suggestions I've come across is Bumblebee but what I've read so far makes it sound specific to nvidia + intelHD builds.

I'm about at the point where I throw my hands up in the air and either do a minimal install of ubuntu or gentoo, and roll the desktop install myself.

Comment: Ubu18, Fresh install - black screens! 3 Monitors - Nvidia + APU